# Use this Ajax Call in a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

Hi so basically I have this kind of Ext.Ajax.request, here is how it is generally structured in my case

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            class: thisClass,
            method: thisMethod,
            data: Ext.encode({
                name:myname,
                age:age
            })
        }
    });
```

I would like to put this into a function, with parameters something like this

```
function call_data() { //Ajax Call WRITTEN ABOVE }
```

But the problem is this where I have 
`data: Ext.encode({name:myname,age:age})`

I do not know how to add parameters into this part of the call, I have tried an array but didnt get far. Bear in mind there can be endless parameters added into that part of the code, as the php can have multiple request variables.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: functions accept arguments ... use them ... `function call_data(myname, age) { ... }`

Comment: Im aware of that maybe you didnt understand

Comment: i had something like this call_data(thisClass, thisMethod)

Comment: perhaps, but you can't deal with `endless parameters` as they won't end

Comment: But when it comes to the data:Ext.encode part i can put as many parameters as I want to send in request. I need a way to account for all the possible inputs. so I can have myname, age, colorOfHair etc

Comment: Yes true, but that's why I tried an array

Comment: just use an object? `Ext.encode(someObject)` - where `someObject` could be `{name:myname,age:age, somethingElse: blah, etc etc }` ? Perhaps I still don't understand the question

Comment: so maybe something like '{"name":"myname","age":"myage"}'

Comment: Yes you understand, thanks that actually might help you can put that as an answer if you wish

Comment: Jaromanda X please take a look to my question if you can answer  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039544/send-and-receive-data-on-creating-a-new-panel-sencha-touch)

Comment: i have same data problem i am new to sencha touch and extjs

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jaromanda X, I did this which fixed my problem.

```
function call_data(url,thisClass, thisMethod, object) {
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            class: thisClass,
            method: thisMethod,
            data: Ext.encode({
                object
            })
        }
    });
}
```

The call can look something like this

`//call_data('index.php','Search','getData',"[{'searchVal':'hello'}]");`